# The product of sums in boolean function

Tags: boolean

I have a function

A'B'C + AC'D + ABC + BC'D'

I have simplified to

C(A'B' + AB) + C'(AD + BD')

(C + AD + BD')(C' A'B' + AB)

Is this the right course?  The last step is where I am getting stuck.

Comment: What does ' (apostrophe) mean? Is it negation?

Comment: The apostrophe is inversion